# On HTML div, what to do to keep vertical alignement of spans after multiple drag and drop operations?

Tags: html, browser, drag-and-drop, draggable, vertical-alignment

I have developped a Javascript program (code is below) to drag and drop some `<span>` element containing (greek) characters and contained in a simple `<div>` element.

The first time the page is displayed correctly; all characters are **aligned** **vertically**.

I can grow or reduce height or width of Window and all caracters continue to be vertically aligned.

[image]

I can move characters in `<div>` using standard `drag and drop` new JavaScript API.

But something go wrong. The vertical alignment begin to be lost !

After 10 or more move, I see following result

[image]

Normally, the `blue-vertical` bar are not visible but in some situation they appears suddently. Is is not a bug, only a characteristic that I use now to explain what happens.

I have same result on last version (2020) of `Opera`, `Chrome`, `Edge Chromium` and `Firefox`.

On Firefox, when I inspect element, a `space-text` zone is displayed between all `<span>` in `<div>`. After each move, the `space-text` zone between `<span>` dropped and `<span>` target (`<span>` on which draggable `<span>` has been dropped) is removed !

This `space-text` zone visible on Firefox seems to correspond to `blue-vertical` bar displayed on Chrome.

If this is not a browser's bug, what must I do to keep original vertical alignement of `<span>` after moving some `<span>` elements (1 or more) ?

The JavaScript code used is following

```js
$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $('.unicode').attr('draggable', 'True');

    $('.unicode').bind(
        { 
        dragstart: function(ev)
            {
            eDraggable = ev.target;
            }
        ,    
        dragenter: function(ev)
            {
            ev.preventDefault(); // needed for IE
            ev.target.style.color = 'red';
            }
        , 
        dragover: function(ev)
            {
            ev.preventDefault(); // needed for IE
            }
        , 
        dragleave: function(ev)
            {
            ev.target.style.color = 'black';
            }
        ,    
        drop: function(ev)
            {
            ev.target.style.color = 'orange';
            ev.target.parentNode.insertBefore(eDraggable, ev.target.nextSibling);
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
.unicode
    {
    font-size: 32px;
    cursor: pointer;
    min-width: 60px;
    padding: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    }
.unicode:hover
    {
    background-color: yellow;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03B1;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03B2;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03B3;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03B4;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03B5;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03B6;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03B7;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03B8;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03B9;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03BA;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03BB;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03BC;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03BD;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03BE;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03BF;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03C0;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03C1;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03C2;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03C3;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03C4;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03C5;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03C6;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03C7;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03C8;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03C9;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x0391;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x0392;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x0393;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x0394;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x0395;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x0396;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x0397;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x0398;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x0399;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x039A;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x039B;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x039C;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x039D;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x039E;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x039F;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03A0;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03A1;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03A3;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03A4;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03A5;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03A6;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03A7;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03A8;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03A9;</span>
</div>
```

In last minute, I have changed font color of dropped `<span>` to facilitate analyse of issue. You can see that only all characters of all lines without dropped `<span>` (all characters are in black) continue to be aligned vertically.

[image]

I have also replaced Unicode by a simple 'X' character to be sure that this issues has nothing to do whith Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is not a bug ... but this is very tricky to understand.

Each `Unicode` characters is contained in a `<span>`. For readability of HTML file on Notepad++, I have generated a file in which each `<span>` is on 1 line like this

```
<div>
    <span class='unicode' title='0x1F600: '>&#x1F600;</span>
    <span class='unicode' title='0x1F601: '>&#x1F601;</span>
    <span class='unicode' title='0x1F600: '>&#x1F600;</span>
    <span class='unicode' title='0x1F601: '>&#x1F601;</span>
</div>
```

The SPACES at start of each line is transformed to 1 space that each browser display between each `<span>`.

All this is explained on https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

If I write all `<span>` on only 1 line, the problem is solved but the generated HTML file is not more readable without a specific formatting.

As explained on `css-tricks.com`, **the simple solution was to reduce container font's size to zero.**

```
div {
    font-size: 0;
    }
```

**Another advantage:**

Before, when I try to drop a `<span>` just hover a space, drop action was refused !

Now that this space has been removed, all location between 2 `<span>` can be dropped.

The new HTML-CSS-Javascript code is following

```js
$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $('.unicode').attr('draggable', 'True');

    $('.unicode').bind(
        { 
        dragstart: function(ev)
            {
            eDraggable = ev.target;
            }
        ,    
        dragenter: function(ev)
            {
            ev.preventDefault(); // needed for IE
            ev.target.style.color = 'red';
            }
        , 
        dragover: function(ev)
            {
            ev.preventDefault(); // needed for IE
            }
        , 
        dragleave: function(ev)
            {
            ev.target.style.color = 'black';
            }
        ,    
        drop: function(ev)
            {
            ev.target.style.color = 'orange';
            ev.target.parentNode.insertBefore(eDraggable, ev.target.nextSibling);
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
.unicode
    {
    font-size: 32px;
    cursor: pointer;
    min-width: 60px;
    padding: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    }
.unicode:hover
    {
    background-color: yellow;
    }
div {    
    font-size:0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03B1;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03B2;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03B3;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03B4;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03B5;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03B6;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03B7;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03B8;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03B9;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03BA;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03BB;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03BC;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03BD;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03BE;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03BF;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03C0;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03C1;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03C2;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03C3;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03C4;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03C5;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03C6;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03C7;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03C8;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03C9;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x0391;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x0392;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x0393;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x0394;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x0395;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x0396;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x0397;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x0398;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x0399;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x039A;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x039B;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x039C;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x039D;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x039E;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x039F;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03A0;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03A1;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03A3;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03A4;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03A5;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03A6;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03A7;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03A8;</span>
  <span class='unicode'>&#x03A9;</span>
</div>
```